# Magento 2: My Headless PWA store front guest and registered customer cart redirect to magento checkout page but need to know how we redirect

Tags: progressive-web-apps, magento2, checkout, pwa-studio

Hi I have a website which have **PWA** **Storefront** with **Magento 2.4.4** version.

**Below is my requirement:**

I added product to the cart and set billing and shipping address also I selected the shipping method in **PWA Store front.**

For payment selection I want to redirect current session/cart From **PWA Storefront** to the **Magento store front** .

On the magento store Front I want to place order and after place order from magento store front redirect back to the PWA Studio

How I will achieve above requirement. Please help

Comment: Hi, Are you using Upward connector? If yes then go to Store > Configuration > General > Web > UPWARD PWA Configuration and set URLs whitelist. Make sure to sync cart.

Comment: How we will go on the magento 2 storefront for payment  with upward